# LaTeX Error: Encoding Scheme `15' unknown

Tags: errors, lyx, font-encodings

So I just finished a document I need to turn in before midnight, but I can't export to PDF for some reason. It keeps showing me this picture:

[image]

My guess is that I'm missing some kind of package?

The error log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.10.7)  7 OCT 2015 21:21
**Afleverings_Opgave_2.tex
(./Afleverings_Opgave_2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `15enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.104 \ProcessOptions*
                    
Necessary code for this encoding was not loaded.
Thus calling the encoding later on will produce further error messages.

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault
                                 \selectfont
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/luainputenc.sty"
Package: luainputenc 2010/11/19 v0.973 inputenc package for LuaTeX
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty"
Package: luatexbase 2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro pro
grammer
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex.sty"
Package: luatex 2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/misc/etex.sty"
Package: etex 2015/07/08 v2.3 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count87
)
\LuT@AllocAttribute=\count277
\LuT@AllocCatcodeTable=\count278
\CatcodeTableStack=\count279
\CatcodeTableIniTeX=\catcodetable1
\CatcodeTableString=\catcodetable3
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable5
\CatcodeTableLaTeX=\catcodetable7
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty"
Package: luatex-loader 2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua))) ("C:
/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty"
Package: luatexbase-compat 2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.s
ty"
Package: luatexbase-modutils 2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-loader 2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua))
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-modutils 2013/05/11 0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-regs.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-regs 2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-attr.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-attr 2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/attr.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-attr 2013/05/11 0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
\lltxb@attr@unsetvalue=\count280
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-cctb.sty
"
Package: luatexbase-cctb 2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/cctb.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-cctb 2013/05/11 0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
\lltxb@catcodetable@alloc=\count281
\CatcodeTableStack=\count282
\CatcodeTableIniTeX=\luatexcatcodetable1
\CatcodeTableString=\luatexcatcodetable3
\CatcodeTableOther=\luatexcatcodetable5
\CatcodeTableLaTeX=\luatexcatcodetable7
\CatcodeTableLaTeXAtLetter=\luatexcatcodetable9
\CatcodeTableExpl=\luatexcatcodetable11
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-mcb.sty"
Package: luatexbase-mcb 2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-mcb 2013/05/11 0.6 register several functions in a callba
ck
))
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/luainputenc.lua)
Lua module: luainputenc 2010/05/10 0.97 Lua simple inputenc package.
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/lutf8.def"
File: lutf8.def 2010/05/10 v0.97 UTF-8 support for luainputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingT1
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingOT1
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingOMS
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
)) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty"
Package: babel 2015/08/03 3.9m The Babel package
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/00miktex/bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/babel-english/english.ldf"
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/babel/babel.def"
File: babel.def 2015/08/03 3.9m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count283
\U@D=\dimen256
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def"
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua)
luatex-hyphen: using data file: C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/generic/config/lan
guage.dat.lua))
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
No file Afleverings_Opgave_2.aux.

\openout1 = Afleverings_Opgave_2.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \begin{document}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 17.

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.64 \item C
          entrum -2,6 og radius = $|AB|=\sqrt{74}$
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.64 \item C
          entrum -2,6 og radius = $|AB|=\sqrt{74}$
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[1

{C:/Users/Vipar/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.105 ... $r=\sqrt{56}\approx7,48331$\end{enumerate}
                                                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.105 ... $r=\sqrt{56}\approx7,48331$\end{enumerate}
                                                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[2]

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.107 \end{document}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `15' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.107 \end{document}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[3] (./Afleverings_Opgave_2.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1478 strings out of 494701
 100000,89155 words of node,token memory allocated
 271 words of node memory still in use:
    nodes
   avail lists: 2:14,3:176,4:1019,5:91,6:865,7:16,9:302,10:33
 5075 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 38 fonts using 1073199 bytes
 39i,6n,23p,216b,240s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><<
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><<C:
/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><<C:/Pr
ogram Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><<C:/Progr
am Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><<C:/Program 
Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><<C:/Program Fil
es (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb><<C:/Program Files (
x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><<C:/Program Files (x86)
/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><<C:/Program Files (x86)/M
iKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy5.pfb><<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKT
eX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb>
Output written on Afleverings_Opgave_2.pdf (3 pages, 119390 bytes).

PDF statistics: 56 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Here is an export of the LyX document I'm using in TeX format:

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[15]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Afleveringsopgave 2}


\author{omitted}

\maketitle
1) Lad der været givet to vektorer i planen, $\vec{a}=({3\atop 8})$
og $\vec{b}=({1\atop 6})$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Beregn $\vec{a}*\vec{b}$

\begin{enumerate}
\item $(3*1)+(8*6)=51$
\end{enumerate}
\item Beregn vinklen mellem $\vec{a}$ og $\vec{b}$

\begin{enumerate}
\item $cos(v)=\frac{51}{\sqrt{3^{2}+8^{2}}*\sqrt{1^{2}+6^{2}}}=\frac{51}{\sqrt{2701}}$
\item $cos^{-1}(\frac{51}{\sqrt{2701}})\approx11,0937$
\item $180-11,0937\approx168,906$
\end{enumerate}
\item Beregn $\vec{a_{b}}$

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{a_{b}}=\frac{({3\atop 8})*({4\atop 6})}{8^{2}+6^{2}}*({1\atop 6})=\frac{60}{100}*({1\atop 6})=({0,6\atop 3,6})$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
2) Lad der i planen være givet punkterne $A(-2,6)$ og $B(5,1)$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bestem en ligning (på formen $ax+by+c=0$) for linjen, som går gennem
punktet $P(1,1)$ og har $\vec{AB}$ som normalvektor.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{AB}=\vec{n}$
\item $\vec{n}=[{5-(-2)\atop 1-6}]=[{7\atop -5}]$
\item $7(x-1)-5(y-1)=0$
\item $7x-7-5y-5=0$
\item $7x-5y-12=0$
\end{enumerate}
\item Bestem en ligning (på formen $ax+by+c=0$) for linjen, som går gennem
punktet $Q(2,-3)$ og har$\vec{AB}$ som retningsvektor.

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{r}=\vec{AB}=[{7\atop -5}]$
\item $\vec{n}=[{5\atop 7}]$
\item $5(x-2)+7(y-(-3))=0$
\item $5x-10+7y-(-21)=0$
\item $5x+7y+11=0$
\end{enumerate}
\item Bestem en ligning for den cirkel, som har centrum i punktet A og har
radius = $|AB|$

\begin{enumerate}
\item Centrum -2,6 og radius = $|AB|=\sqrt{74}$
\item $r=\sqrt{(5-(-2))^{2}+(1-6)^{2}}=\sqrt{74}$
\item $(x-(-2))^{2}+(y-6)^{2}\approx8,60233^{2}$
\item $(x+2)^{2}+(y-6)^{2}=74$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
3) Lad der i planen være givet punkterne P(7,2) og Q(1,3)
\begin{enumerate}
\item Beregn vinklen mellem $\vec{PQ}$ og x-aksen

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\vec{x}=[{1\atop 0}]$
\item $\vec{PQ}=[{1-7\atop 3-2}]=[{-6\atop 1}]$
\item $cos(v)=\frac{[{-6*1\atop 1*0}]}{\sqrt{(-6)^{2}+1^{2}}*\sqrt{1^{2}+0^{2}}}=\frac{-5}{\sqrt{37}}$
\item $cos^{-1}(\frac{-5}{\sqrt{37}})\approx145,285$
\item $180-145,285=34,715$
\end{enumerate}
\item Beregn midtpunktet af linjestykket PQ

\begin{enumerate}
\item $M=(\frac{7+1}{2},\frac{2+3}{2})=(4,2.5)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
5) Bestem tallet t, således at vektorene $\vec{a}=({t+1\atop 4})$
og $\vec{b}=({t^{2}-2t\atop -t})$ er ortogonale.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $({t+1\atop 4})*({t^{2}-2t\atop -t})=0$
\item $t^{3}-2t+t^{2}-2t-4t=0$
\item $t^{3}-t^{2}-6t=0$
\item $t*(t^{2}-t-6)=0$
\item $t=0$
\item $t^{2}-t-6=0$
\item $1t^{2}-1t-6=0$
\item $d=(-1)^{2}-4*1*(-6)=25$
\item $t=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{25}}{2*1}=\{{3\atop -2}$
\item Løsnigen er enten 3 eller -2.
\end{enumerate}
6) Bestem centrum og radius for cirklen $x^{2}+y^{2}-16x+12y-44=0$
\begin{enumerate}
\item $(x-8)^{2}+(y+6)^{2}+44=0$
\item $(-44)+6^{2}+8^{2}=56$
\item Centrum (8,-6) og $r=\sqrt{56}\approx7,48331$\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Also attached my file as a [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6spj868d5d6q215/Afleverings%20Opgave%202.lyx?dl=0) in case you want to have a look at it.

Hope you guys can help me out! :)

Comment: I don't use Lyx, but your link shows you're writing in a language with accents so the encoding for LaTeX should be `T1`, and the font used shouldn't be the default (Computer Modern) but Latin Modern instead (package `lmodern`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Documents > Settings > Fonts, change the LaTeX font encoding from Custom to Default:

[image]

There exists no `15` font encoding, hence the error `15enc.def` not found. I assume you don't need any special font encoding.

Comment: Ah, I thought I changed the font size with that...my bad! Do you know how I make the Math font bigger though? Some of it is almost unreadable.

Comment: @Vipar: Inline math is usually set to `\textstyle`. You might be interested in `\displaystyle` instead. For this you'll have to select the object in question, click on the math style select and choose "Display".